# find only the duplicate values in listagg

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, oracle12c, listagg

I am having some duplicate rows in my table. I wanted to find those duplicates.

[image]

After i have done listagg on the column rp_num  my table will have duplicate value like this :

```
 SELECT distinct vt.vsd_id, vt.rn,vt.rp_id,
 LISTAGG(vt.rp_num,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Nlssort(vt.rp_num, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI')) 
                  over (PARTITION BY vt.vsd_id, vt.rn,vt.rp_id ) vp_num_gruppe 
             FROM   vechicle_datatype vt
            where vt.vsd_id = 37897;
```

[image]

I wanted to select only those duplicate values in rp_num_group (after the listagg on rp_num column).
I tried using count(*) for the listagg but it doesnt work.

I wanted to select only those values mentioned below :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the analytical function as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT T.*, 
        COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY VT.VSD_ID, VT.RN, VP_NUM_GRUPPE) AS CNT
   FROM (SELECT VT.VSD_ID, VT.RN, VT.RP_ID,
                LISTAGG(VT.RP_NUM,' ') WITHIN GROUP(
                   ORDER BY NLSSORT(VT.RP_NUM,'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI')) AS VP_NUM_GRUPPE
           FROM VECHICLE_DATATYPE VT
          WHERE VT.VSD_ID = 37897
       GROUP BY VT.VSD_ID, VT.RN, VT.RP_ID)T )
 WHERE CNT > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregate form of `listagg()`, and filter with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT 
    vsd_id, 
    rn,
    rp_id,
    LISTAGG(rp_num,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Nlssort(rp_num, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI')) vp_num_gruppe 
FROM  vechicle_datatype vt
WHERE vt.vsd_id = 37897
GROUP BY vsd_id, rn, rp_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks i tried it. I wanted the duplicated that comes after the listagg on the column rp_num.